# Can I put a video with a transparent background in a videoview

Tags: android, transparent, android-videoview

I'd like to place the view described in the title over another view (GridView) in an android app so the "bottom" GridView is visible through the transparency in the video?

Comment: No reason to down vote everybody, I understand what this person is asking. (ALTHOUGH IT COULD BE WORDED BETTER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this but it may be possible by using setAlpha on the video view

Comment: alpha setting did not do it...it seems that what we wanted to achieve (something like when you see a person 'walk out' onto a web page) was not possible

Comment: if you set alpha, the whole view becomes transparency